# time.Unix(t, offset) gives same time?

Tags: go, time

Trying to obtain successive timestamps with below Go code

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "time"

func main () {
    ts := int64(1500000000)  // start
    for i := int64(0); i<1e6; i = i + 1000 { // successively add 1e3
            t := time.Unix(ts, i)  // Get start + i
            fmt.Printf("%d %02d:%02d\n", ts+i, t.Hour(), t.Minute())
    }
}
```

, output remains like

```
....
1500995000 04:40
1500996000 04:40
1500997000 04:40
1500998000 04:40
1500999000 04:40
```

Please, what is the problem here ? Why the hour:minute doesn't vary ? (04:40)

`go version go1.15.6 linux/amd64`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are changing the nanoseconds and printing minutes...

https://pkg.go.dev/time@go1.16.7#Unix

```
func Unix(sec int64, nsec int64) Time
```

Check this:
https://play.golang.org/p/_Ywn9S5Khch

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "time"

func main () {
    ts := int64(1500000000)  // start
    for i := int64(0); i<1e6; i = i + 1000 { // successively add 1e3
            t := time.Unix(ts, i)  // Get start + i
            fmt.Printf("%d %02d:%02d ---- %2d\n", ts+i, t.Hour(), t.Minute(), t.UnixNano())
    }
}
```